# При подключении api yandex maps происходит ошибка 403 forbidden

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подключаю скрипт

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;coordorder=longlat" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

на локальном сервере, происходит ошибка 403 forbidden. Если подключить этот скрипт на js fiddle то все нормально подключается.

Comment: О проблемах с доступностью API стоит обращаться в техподдержку. Это не проблема Вашего кода. 
Ошибка 403 Forbidden означает, что для Вашего сайта или ip адреса запрещен доступ к API Яндекс.Карт. Причиной может быть автоматическая блокировка за нарушение условий использования.
Вам нужно обратиться в саппорт Яндекса

Answer (score 3):

В саппорте ответили что это из-за referer localhost. Пришлось установить расширение https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=ru которое меняет referer.

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` -- этого не должно быть в ссылке, правильно `&`.